# Passing Command Parameter to delete a list view entry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Menu Item which can delete the entry in the ListView. My problem is the Command Parameter I'm passing is always null.

List View `

```
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ContactImage, Source={x:Reference contactsListView}}" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="15,0,0,0"></Image>
                            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" VerticalOptions="Center"></Label>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Favorite, Converter={StaticResource FavoriteImageConverter}}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference contactsListView}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding FullName}"/>

                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PhoneImage, Source={x:Reference contactsListView}}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,15,0">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding BindingContext.CallCommand, Source={x:Reference contactsListView}}" 
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ContactNumber}"/>
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>

                        </StackLayout>

                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <MenuItem  Text="Edit" IsDestructive="False" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}" BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.EditMenu}"/>
                            <MenuItem  Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" 
                                       Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}" 
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding FullName}" 
                                       BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteMenu}"/>
                        </ViewCell.ContextActions>


                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>`
```

If I change the CommandParameter to `CommandParameter = "test", the test string is properly passed`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Where is your `ItemsSource`, what is inside it?

Comment: My ItemSource is a `list<Contact>contacts` and full name is definitely there as the `tap gesture recognizer` which uses the `Binding FullName` as well works fine

Comment: instead of binding to FullName for your command parameter , try to use the dot "."
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"

Comment: Unfortunately it is still null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML you are defining your delete `MenuItem` with is

```
<MenuItem  
    Text="Delete" 
    IsDestructive="True" 
    Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding FullName}" 
    BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference contactsListView}, Path=BindingContext.DeleteMenu}" />
```

Since this is located within your `DataTemplate`, the default `BindingContext` of the `ViewCell` is the single `Contact` associated with the list item, which has the property `FullName`.

Anyway, you are explicitly setting the `BindingContext` of the menu item. Since the `CommandParameter` is bound to the `BindingContext` of the `MenuItem` XF will try to update `CommandParameter` when your `BindingContext` changes. But since `DeleteMenu` has not got a property `FullName`, the `CommandParameter` will be `null`. It should work if you didn't set the `BindingContext` explicitly, since in this case the `BindingContext` was the one of the parent, which is your `Contact`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your ListView has being filled with a set of view models, you can reference the model your MenuItem Command got invoked from via:

```
<ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <MenuItem Clicked="OnEdit" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Edit" IsDestructive="false" />
    <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Löschen" IsDestructive="true" />
</ViewCell.ContextActions>
```

Where "." is a short for the current item of your listview items source (Just leave the dot in there as it is. Looks wrong but works).